# Instanced node isn't visible when ran

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I have a Grid, which extends TileMap, and I'm trying to spawn panels in. Panels extend Area2D.

The hierarchy:
Main scene -> player grid scene -> grid scene -> [player scene, x number of panel scenes (added via spawn_panels function)].

Please note that these are all the above are added in the 2D editor, and only the panels are added via script.

To spawn the panels, I have this function ran in _ready in Grid:

```
func spawn_panels(charType):
  var panelInit = null
  var panel = null
  var childPanel = null

  if charType == PLAYER:
      panelInit = AllyPanel
  elif charType == ENEMY:
      panelInit = EnemyPanel

  for x in grid_s_x:
      for y in grid_s_y:
          panel = panelInit.new(x, y)
          self.add_child(panel)
          panel.set_owner(self)
          panel.set_name("panel" + str(x) + str(y))
          panel.position = map_to_world(Vector2(x, y)) + cell_size / 2
```

However, the panels are not visible when the game is ran. I have printed the tree and can see that they are added properly, and also verified that they are not added out of bounds as I've hard coded their position to 0, 0 and the player position (player is visible) but it is still not visible.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out GDScript doens't like it when you add an instance created from .new() and add it to the node tree. This means that you must preload / load it (as opposed to referencing it through a class) then add it that way.

ie:

```
var a = preload("res://a.tscn")
add_child(a)
```